# My recycler view not shown for the first time in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-mvvm

**I am a beginner at android development. I tried to display data on Recycle View using MVVM. When I opened the fragment the first time it is empty, the second time it showed data. Adapter not called the first time. How to fix this.**

**Fragment class**

```
public class fragmentEmployee extends Fragment {

private FragmentEmployeeBinding binding;
private ViewGroup viewGroup;
private View view;
private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
private UserAdapter mAdapter;
private EmployeeRegisterViewModel viewModel;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_employee, viewGroup, false);
    view = binding.getRoot();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onViewCreated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mRecycleView = binding.recyleViewEmployee;
    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EmployeeRegisterViewModel.class);
    viewModel.init();
    initRecycleView();
    viewModel.getEmployee().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<employeeModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<employeeModel> employeeModels) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private void initRecycleView() {
    mAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), viewModel.getEmployee().getValue());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

**UserAdapter** class

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

public List<employeeModel> employeeModelList= new ArrayList<>();
public Context context1;

public UserAdapter(Context context,List<employeeModel> employeeModels){
    employeeModelList = employeeModels;
    context1 = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   (ViewHolder)holder).username.setText(employeeModelList.get(position).getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return employeeModelList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView username;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    username=itemView.findViewById(R.id.userText);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try reordering like this.

**Remove**

```
mAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), viewModel.getEmployee().getValue());
```

from **initRecycleView**

```
mAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), viewModel.getEmployee().getValue());

viewModel.getEmployee().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<employeeModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<employeeModel> employeeModels) {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
initRecycleView();
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. but first time I cant see my data list. Second time I can see data list.

Answer (score 1):

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Above method will work if the list declared inside adapter has any change. So, calling above method without changing adapter's list is useless.

Add a method to UserAdapter class to update list data. Like:

```
 public void updateData(List<employeeModel> updatedList){
    employeeModelList.clear();
    employeeModelList.addAll(updatedList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this method inside observer. Like:

```
viewModel.getEmployee().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new 
Observer<List<employeeModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<employeeModel> employeeModels) {
        mAdapter.updateData(employeeModels);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you logged data size inside observer ?

Answer (score 0):

where are you get your network data?

If your get in here -> viewModel.init();
I think it just timing problem.

Just change code sequence

```
initRecycleView();
viewModel.getEmployee().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<employeeModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<employeeModel> employeeModels) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
viewModel.init();
```